# How to fix: if you plugin your earphone after you started the game, it will not output sound?

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, volume-mixer

***Problem::***

If you plug in your earphone after you start the game, you cannot hear any sound from the game.

- To fix it, you have to restart the game, then you can get sound from
  the game.
- Or, plug in the earphone before you start the game.

How to fix this permanently, so that I can plug in my earphone whenever I want, instead of restarting the game every time?

Why does that happen?

***Note::***

My earphone and the computer is working fine with all the other software (they all have sound, only the game doesn't, only the game does not show up in the volume mixer).

The game refers to csgo (also some other games).

Comment: Routing sound to the headphone jack is a function of the sound card circuitry, not Windows.  For instance, on *my* setup, Realtek provides an annoying popup to choose where the sound goes upon plug-in.  There is no option to select a default.  If I disable the popup, I can't use the headphones at all.  Your specific hardware will need to be known if there is even a hope of helping you.

Comment: I'd ask the developers. I used to run support on a game that would only enumerate input/output options at launch, so anything added afterwards it simply could not know it was there.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I think I am using "Realtek High Definition Audio". 
But I can still use the earphone when I disable the popup in its setting.